# How to construct Cauchy sequences for proof of completeness or incompleteness?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complete-spaces

I wanted to prove that the space of continuous functions and also the space of differentiable functions are not complete but I don't know how to construct a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge to these spaces?

The metric of the continuous function is the *sup* metric and the metric of the metric of the differentiable functions is:

$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}$max|D$^\alpha$*f*(**x**) - D$^\alpha$*g*(**x**)|

where D$^\alpha$ is the multi-index notation. The functions of both spaces are defined on a bounded domain of **R**$^n$.

Another question is that "Where do exactly these sequences come from?", I mean when I faced a problem concerning the completeness of a space, "How should I construct such a sequence?".

Is there a special "tip" for that?

Thank you so much for sharing your experience.

Comment: What is your metric?

Comment: The completeness of various sets of real-valued functions is dependent on how you define a norm (the "distance" between two functions used to define convergence).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are right. I have added the metrics. If there was any other problem I will correct as you say. Thank you.

Comment: @Kajelad The metrics are added. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set is complete, you need to show that the limit of any Cauchy sequence must be a member of the set. If the set is not complete, you need to find a Cauchy sequences that converges to a limit outside of the set.

For the continuous case, the first approach will work. It looks like you are looking at the set of continuous functions from some bounded subset $S\in\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, using the sup norm:

$$||f-g||=sup\{|f(\mathbf x)-g(\mathbf x)|,\ \mathbf x\in S\}$$

We then let $f_n:S\to\mathbb R$ be s Cauchy sequence of continuous functions.

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N,\ s.t.\ n,m>N\implies ||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$$

choosing a particular $\mathbf x$:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N,\ s.t.\ n,m>N\implies |f_n(\mathbf x)-f_m(\mathbf x)|<\epsilon$$

This means that $f_n$ coverges pointwise. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete, we know there is a function $f:S\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(\mathbf x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(\mathbf x)$ and that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N,\ s.t.\ n>N\implies ||f_n-f||<\epsilon$$

We now need to show $f$ is continuous, starting from the statement that every $f_n$ is continuous:

$$\forall \mathbf x\in S,\ \forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists \delta\ s.t.\ ||\mathbf y-\mathbf x||<\delta\implies |f_n(\mathbf y)-f_n(\mathbf x)|<\epsilon$$

Here $||\mathbf y-\mathbf x||$ indicates a euclidean distance. We can now construct the contiuity statement for $f$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $\mathbf x\in S$.

$$\exists n\ s.t.\ ||f_n-f||<\frac\epsilon 3\implies\ sup\{|f_n(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf x)|,\ x\in S\}<\frac\epsilon 3$$

$$\exists \delta\ s.t.\ ||\mathbf y-\mathbf x||<\delta\implies|f_n(\mathbf y)-f_n(\mathbf x)|<\frac\epsilon 3$$

By triangle inequality:

$$|f(\mathbf y)-f(\mathbf x)|\le|f(\mathbf y)-f_n(\mathbf y)|+|f_n(\mathbf y)-f_n(\mathbf x)|+|f_n(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf x)|$$

The inequalities above force each of these terms to be strictly less than $\frac\epsilon 3$. Therefore the $\delta$ chosen above is sufficient to say:

$$||\mathbf y-\mathbf x||<\delta\implies|f(\mathbf y)-f(\mathbf x)|<\epsilon$$

Which by definition means the limit function $f$ is continuous. Since this can be applied to *any* Cauchy sequence of continuous functions, the set is complete.

I'm not familiar with the notation for the metric for differentiable functions, so I can't say anything about completeness. If it is complete, a similar proof will probably be needed. If it is not complete, you can choose a familiar function that is *not* everywhere differentiable like $f(\mathbf x)=||\mathbf x||$ and find a way to approach it with differentialbe functions so that the norm goes to $0$.

Comment: You're right. So we have to find a Cauchy sequence which tend to f(x) = |x|. I suppose that the Cauchy sequence f$_n$ = |x|$^(1+1/n)$ converges to f(x) which is not differentiable at point 0. We just have to prove that f$_n$(x) is a Cauchy sequence according to the norm defined above. Am I on the right path?

Comment: $f_n$ also has to be differentiable over all $S$. Sequences like $f_n(\mathbf x)=\frac{||\mathbf x||^2}{\sqrt{\frac 1n+||\mathbf x||^2}}$ have this property while still approaching a non-differentiable function. Depending on the norm used, this may not be a Cauchy sequence. In fact, there may not be *any* Cauchy sequences that converge to a non-differentiable function. If that is the case, a proof of completeness is needed.